# How to display the message of login account deleted(soft delete)

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, authentication

I developed function to delete users (soft deletion), ie stays in the database and does not show in the list. When I enter the login and password of the deleted account, it have to show a message as **this login is deleted**.

how to achieve this and thanks

user.controller.cs:

```
[Route("api/Users/Login")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(object))]
        public async Task<object> accountLogin(string name, string password)
        {

            string pwd = Encrypt(password);
            Users account = new Users();

            var query = from c in db.Users
                        where c.userlogin == name && c.password == pwd
                        select c;

            account = query.FirstOrDefault();

            string message = "";

            if (account == null)
            {
                message += "404";
            }
            else if (account .IsActive == 1)
            {
                message += "400";
            }
            else if ((account .IsActive != 0) && (account .IsActive != 1)) // this condition of account deleted -- or account .IsActive == 2
            {
                message += "500";
            }

            else
            {
                message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account);
            }

            return new { a = message };

        }
```

and this login.controller.js:

```
$scope.login = function () {
                $scope.loading = true;
                authService.login($scope.userlogin)
                    .then(function done(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response.a == '400') {
                                $scope.error = 'account disabled';
                                $scope.loading = false;
                            }
                            else if (response.a == '500') {
                                $scope.error = 'this login is deleted';
                                $scope.loading = false;
                            }
                            else if (response != '404') {
                                console.log("bbb");
                                $location.url('Dashboard');
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("login or password incorrect");
                                $scope.error = 'login or password incorrect';
                                $scope.loading = false;
                            }
                        },
                        function fail(err) {
                            $scope.error = 'Problem in connextion ! contact administrateur';
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    );
            }
```

Comment: When the account was deleted and user is trying to login means, you need to show as "Account deleted". Is this is what you are trying to say?

Comment: Hi Sivabalan, yes

Comment: It will deleted from table or still will be there?

Comment: is still will be table

Comment: So you can make column as is_deleted. When you deleted the column change the status as 1 and change the query as `select * from user where email=xxx and is_deleted <> 1`

Comment: now, when the user will be connected by a deleted account, a message displays the response "404" (login or password deleted) and not response "500" (this login is deleted)

Comment: Then you can use this query ` select password, is_deleted from user where email=xxx` and if is_deleted is 1 show 404 else check the password login.

Comment: while checking for the username and password match before that do a check with the username (hope it will be unique) whether the user status (your matching table column) is active or not (0 or 1) based on that send a response to your web thats it Hope it will help you

Comment: Securitywise and dataprotectionwise (remember GDPR) it is not a good idea to show such a message as it exposes the existence of the emailaddress/account and the association with your website.